# Make stream_socket_client faster with gethostbyname?

Tags: php, sockets

We are opening around 100 connections with stream_socket_client to different websites.

Sometimes this takes a while, my assumption is because of IP address resolving (for example up to 40 seconds, then on repeat try 4-5 seconds).

I know we can cache IP addresses in the software as well (get them with gethostbyname) but the problem is that some sites are on shared IPs, and some sites use subdomains (same IP as main domain). So if we used IP only the requests would always go to the same place instead of different sites on that IP.

Is there a workaround so we can increase the speed and target the sites we want?

Comment: What is php's system resource load when you have all of your connections open? What is your server environment like?

Comment: the load is minimal it is a 16 core server, running CentOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNS caching is an excellent idea, but I recommend doing it outside your application; I've used [PowerDNS recursor](http://doc.powerdns.com/built-in-recursor.html) with excellent results for years now, it is good solid code. (PDNS avoided some headline-making security flaws that plagued BIND by learning from Dan Bernstein's DNS recursor software.)

By doing the caching outside your application, you avoid completely the concern you had about trying to match the IP with the correct `Host:` headers in your requests, *and* you get complete access to DNS's built-in caching intelligence. (PDNS will respect the Time To Live of results, something that would take your team effort to re-implement correctly.)

But I assume a great part of the problem is that the DNS requests are probably being made sequentially in your application, *after* the previous one has returned. If you're going to be hitting the same 100 names all day long, then using PDNS-recursor on its own will probably suffice.

If the 100 names per request don't have much overlap, then you'll probably need to *parallelize the DNS requests* made by your application, so that you can have 100 outstanding DNS requests simultaneously, rather than just one outstanding request simultaneously. One 'cheap' approach is handing off all requests to an external program that kicks off a few dozen threads and makes requests for all the names. (And drops them on the floor. Rely on PDNS-recursor to cache them all.) A little more work is to create a few dozen threads or processes directly in your PHP program to do all the lookups. This would either let you use the answers directly, or again, pre-populate your PDNS-recursor cache before your old sequential code does the lookups.

And the most work of all would be moving completely to asynchronous DNS requests, such as the `libadns` library provides. This would provide most benefit if there is *no* overlap between different bursts of 100 name lookups.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily speed up the the resolvement if you enter the hostnames and ip addresses into the hosts file (`/etc/hosts` on *nix machines, `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows machines).

You may have to change the configuration in `/etc/host.conf` (I don't know where to change for Windows) because by default the first try is to ask the named and then check the `/etc/hosts` file.

To be sure how the `gethostbyname` function works that is implemented in your system, try to find the correct man page (i.e. http://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyname).

Comment: This is not a solution because we have thousands of sites and it does not solve a problem when there are two sites (with different domains) on a shared IP.